# PHP or NodeJS for a chat app with message queue

Tags: php, node.js, message-queue, asynchronous

In my company I proposed NodeJS for developing a microservice that acts as a bridge between the front-end and a third party chat API, that Microservice will receive large amounts of messages (about 1000 or more) at once, that will have to be able to queue using Amazon Simple Queue Service.

I have already developed a proof of concept that does something similar with NodeJS, however the company is not willing to use NodeJS, stating that the rest of technical team doesn't know the technology.

Is NodeJs a more optimal option to develop such a service? 
What potential drawbacks can PHP eventually have if we use it in this case?

Comment: Either language will work well enough, assuming the rest of the stack can keep up.

Comment: Is it not NodeJS more suitable due to its natural event-driven architecture and asynchronicity for real-time apps? PHP cannot accept concurrent request as far as I know, also having to initialize php, database, configs, etc... for every request seems overkilling, NodeJS initializes only once and listens indefinitely, to me it makes more sense.

Comment: None of Node's apparent advantages is worth the bus factor introduced by having one person who knows how to use it. PHP can do event-driven and async and long-running services too, it's just not very common.

Comment: I don't get the downvote, at least provide some feedback so we can improve our questions, we cannot read minds (whoever it was)

Comment: @cHao what about the bus factor of having overloaded CPU's, delay requests, slow user experience, potential crashes, etc...? Is compromising the business a reason to dismiss a technology?

Comment: Google "bus factor". It's not a technical problem; it's a people problem.

Comment: I the downvote is due to the fact that you basically ask to compare two technologies (PHP vs Node).

Comment: see [Gorilla vs. Shark](http://blog.stackoverflow.com/2011/08/gorilla-vs-shark/) -- _"if you... don’t want your question to get instantly closed... — try to keep Gorilla vs. Shark in mind."_

Comment: Would you please tell me what is the right place to ask for "Gorilla vs. Shark" type of questions, because a have a lot...

Answer (score 1):

If you have people who are familiar with Node, it's a good choice. PHP can do the same stuff Node can with a couple of extensions, but Node is good at that stuff right out of the box.

But frankly, without the technical knowledge, it doesn't matter if Node is the best platform ever. If you get hit by a bus right after you've created your service, no one else has the know-how to fix it if a bug is found.

Managers quite rightly don't want to risk everything on one person's well being and job satisfaction. :P  So they prefer environments that the rest of the team can work with. You can try to teach everyone how to do stuff with Node.js, but you're pretty much going to be stuck with PHP til they've gotten the hang of it.

Either one is pretty easy to scale horizontally, so the choice of technology is not a huge issue from a technical perspective.